# application pool crash with csv upload

Tags: iis, csv

Our website has an application pool. When new data is uploaded by csv it causes the application pool to crash. A call to the hosting company for an IIS reset gets us back again but only until the next upload. Any solutions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! You need to provide more details - what exactly is being done with the CSV file, for example. Show some code, otherwise we can't tell what's wrong with it.

Comment: What kind of application is running at the site? It sounds like the application is buggy and crashes. Could be pointer errors, memory overflows or any other programming error. The server logs should provide some more detailed error messages that can be helpful.

Comment: Any chance that you can get some logs from the server?  The event logs could be useful, might have a stack trace.